# Load big data to List with Python

Tags: python, bigdata

I am running the reprocess code from a paper. The yahoo data-set with 699640226 lines. I run the code and the error was as

````
> 2nd pass training: 359000000 2nd pass training: 360000000 2nd pass
> training: 361000000 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usit/abel/u1/cnphuong/.local/opt/nomad/Scripts/convert.py", line 80,
> in <module>
>     train_values.append(float(tokens[2])) MemoryError```
> 2. I run on server with 32 and 60GB ram but there are the same error. 
> 
> ```python
> # now parse the data train_user_indices = list() train_item_indices = list() train_values = list() for index, line in
> enumerate(open(train_filename)):
>     if index % 1000000 == 0:
>         print "2nd pass training:", index
>     tokens = line.split(" ")
>     train_user_indices.append(user_indexer[tokens[0]])
>     train_item_indices.append(item_indexer[tokens[1]])
>     train_values.append(float(tokens[2]))
````

Please tell me the best way to do to add all data to list because the author can run with the file (~11GB and 699640226)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TensorFlow, there are already tools built in so that you can train over a file structure without having to load the entirety into RAM. See [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets).

Comment: Yes. I thang the train_values to integer. I the list can load the data.